# When I try to install hlint I get errors surrounding old-time-1.1.0.3

Tags: haskell, package, cabal-install, hlint

I first tried to install Hlint. `cabal install hlint` but then I got the error:

```
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cpphs-1.20.2 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to install.
haskell-src-exts-1.18.2 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to install.
hlint-1.9.37 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to install.
old-time-1.1.0.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 77
```

Then I tried to install ghc-mod since I read that hlint is a dependency of that package(?). Thinking that it might resolve the problem. So i did `cabal install ghc-mod` which gave me the error.

```
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cpphs-1.20.2 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to install.
ghc-mod-5.6.0.0 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to install.
haskell-src-exts-1.17.1 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to install.
hlint-1.9.35 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to install.
old-time-1.1.0.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 77
```

So it seems to be the same problem, around my the package `old-time-1.1.0.3`.

Comment: If you want any real hope of such an issue being solved you must include much, much more detail (at the very least the output of the failing command with `-v3`). A quick google search shows this is likely related to a broken installation of gcc (or ghc is using a different c compiler than it should be)

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of variables that could be at play to explain what's going on, including `cabal-install` and `ghc` versions. It would be useful if you included the `cabal --version` and `ghc --version` output in your question.

That said: I'd recommend trying out the installation using [Stack](https://haskell-lang.org/get-started). Once you have Stack installed (on POSIX systems, usually sufficient to run `curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh`), you can install with `stack --resolver lts-6.16 --install-ghc --no-system-ghc install hlint`.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to know where it fails is to go through each failed package and install them one after the other.

I had issue with `haskell-src-exts` in which showed up in `hlint` and when I tried to `cabal install haskell-src-exts` it was `happy`that wasn't properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows or Linux? What does `ghc --version` say? What about `ghc-pkg old-time`? I recommend trying to run `cabal install old-time` directly, which should reproduce the error directly.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Modify your cabal config file (you can verify the location by running "cabal user-config init") to contain the following lines:

```
extra-prog-path: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.1\msys\usr\bin
extra-lib-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.1\mingw\lib
extra-include-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.1\mingw\include
```