# How to install old-time-1.1.0.3 in Windows 7

Tags: haskell

I try to install [old-time-1.1.0.3](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/old-time-1.1.0.3) in windows 7 (GHC version: 8.4.2) using `cabal intall old-time` but not success, here is the error message:

```
Configuring old-time-1.1.0.3...
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 1038: $'with_compiler\r=ghc': command not found
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler
checking for gcc... ../mingw/bin\gcc.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether ../mingw/bin\gcc.exe accepts -g... yes
checking for ../mingw/bin\gcc.exe option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... ../mingw/bin\gcc.exe -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /cygdrive/c/app/gnu/win32/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /cygdrive/c/app/gnu/win32/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... ..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 1606: ${ac_cv_header_sys_types_h
+:}: bad substitution
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'IFS\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `IFS
': not a valid identifier
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'PATH\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `PATH
': not a valid identifier
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'ac_includes_default\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `ac_includes_default
': not a valid identifier
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'ac_ls_di\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `ac_ls_di
': not a valid identifier
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'ac_precious_vars\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `ac_precious_vars
': not a valid identifier
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'ac_pwd_ls_di\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `ac_pwd_ls_di
': not a valid identifier
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'ac_subst_vars\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `ac_subst_vars
': not a valid identifier
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'ac_user_opts\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `ac_user_opts
': not a valid identifier
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'as_bourne_compatible\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `as_bourne_compatible
': not a valid identifier
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'as_nl\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `as_nl
': not a valid identifier
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'as_required\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `as_required
': not a valid identifier
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'as_save_IFS\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `as_save_IFS
': not a valid identifier
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: $'as_suggested\r=': command not found
..\old-time-1.1.0.3\configure: line 23: unset: `as_suggested
': not a valid identifier
cabal: Leaving directory '..\old-time-1.1.0.3'
```

I found a similar post: [When I try to install hlint I get errors surrounding old-time-1.1.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434709/when-i-try-to-install-hlint-i-get-errors-surrounding-old-time-1-1-0-3), but the solution of above post does not work for me.

EDIT:
Here is my cabal config file, the remarked line has been removed:

```
repository hackage.haskell.org
  url: http://hackage.haskell.org/

remote-repo-cache: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\cabal\packages

world-file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\cabal\world

extra-include-dirs: C:\programs\haskell\8.4.2\mingw\include

extra-lib-dirs: C:\programs\haskell\8.4.2\mingw\lib

extra-prog-path: C:\programs\haskell\8.4.2\msys\usr\bin,
                 C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin

symlink-bindir: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin

build-summary: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\build.log

remote-build-reporting: anonymous

jobs: $ncpus
```

EDIT2:

I try to build it manually, but some dependencies missing. Here is the error message:

```
>runhaskell Setup.hs configure --ghc

Configuring old-time-1.1.0.3...
Setup.hs: Encountered missing dependencies:
base >=4.7 && <4.9, old-locale ==1.0.*
```

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: @MarkNeu The old-time version is 1.1.0.3 and GHC version is 8.4.2 on window 7

Comment: Can you show us your Cabal config?

Comment: @Glazbee Sure, the config file of Cabal has been posted, please see the "EDIT" part.

Comment: typo: `intall` -> `install`

Comment: Don't have a windows here, but looks like you're trying to execute a bash script (`./configure`) with something that isn't bash. Try running the build manually via autoconf etc and see if you can control how `./configure` is executed.

Comment: @Reactormonk I tried to build it manually (don't use cabal), but some dependencies are broken.

Comment: It's a start. Which dependencies?

Comment: @Reactormonk It show that `base >=4.7 && <4.9, old-locale ==1.0.*` dependencies is missing. please refers the "EDIT2" in the question.